# SQL Server : trying to add non-null column to an existing table (table is empty)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a new column to my exiting table but I keep getting an error trying to insert non-null columns.

I understand how this would be an issue to existing databases with lots of data, but my database has no data yet so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error.

Is there an easy solution for this (I don't want to add default values)

Comment: Delete the table; Add the same table with the structure you want? If it's got no rows, why is it so precious?

Comment: Please show us an example or preferably the actual 'alter table statement'.  Please show us the exact complete error statement.  Thanks.

Comment: *‘but I keep getting an error trying to insert non-null columns’* – what error exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You've got two options, feed it a default value, or add the field without the non-null constraint, then alter the table later to add the non-null constraint after you've populated the field.

Comment: I tryed the second solution:
Added the columns with nulls allowed
But now it wont let me change them to non-nulls

Comment: You've got to populate them with something before you add the non-null constraint.  Non-NULL field can't be NULL, it's the nature of the beast.

Comment: (No data in the table) Nevermind, after some fiddling I got it to work, tyvm

Answer (score 1):

This works fine when the table is empty.

```
CREATE TABLE X(Y INT)

ALTER TABLE T ADD Y INT NOT NULL
```

There is no need to add a temporary default constraint or create it as `NULL`, populate then `ALTER` except if the table is, in fact, not empty as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that table is as empty as you think it is.

Try this:

```
Truncate Table <YourTableName>
```

Then try the alter table statement.